# Why does this dual Flying V have the tuners on the back body in addition to the headstock?

Tags: electric-guitar

I was watching Dave Mustaine from Megadeth in their [concert DVD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LPS2P4) from Argentina and I was confused by his double neck Flying V:

[image]

I've seen guitars with the tuner "in the back" before, but this is the first time I've seen this configuration. Also, where are the tuning keys for the bottom part?

I know Dave plays Deans these days:

[image]

The guitar in the first image appears to not be a Dean (or a Jackson, which is what he used to play). In other scenes in the DVD it's clear to me that the headstocks have tuners, I just don't understand the ones in the back.

Can someone explain this kind of Flying V and why the tuners are configured the way they are?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The guitar with tuners at the rear is a twelve string.

You can see the ferrules at the rear on the back of the guitar for the strings that are tuned at the headstock and there are ferrules on the headstock for the second set of 6 strings going back in the opposite direction.

Comment: To add to Stuart Colville's answer, I assume this is just for practicality on an electric-style headstock, as a standard acoustic twelve-string has space on both sides of the headstock for tuners. Gotta save space somewhere, I guess.

Comment: Also, it would add a considerable amount of weight to the relatively light headstock that exists, and almost certainly require more wood.